# jQuery lags on validation events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors, validation

The following code seems to cause delays in browsers and Firebug.
What am I doing wrong?

```
$("td input").focus( function(){
    $(this).parent().next().next().css('visibility','visible');            
});
$("td input").blur( function(){
    $(this).parent().next().next().css('visibility','hidden');
    if($(this).val()==""){
        $(this).parent().next().css('visibility','visible');
    }
    else $(this).parent().next().css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

thanks!

Comment: I assume it's due to many records in the table, but you might want to use ".hide()" in stead of "css( 'visiblity', 'hidden' )", also, I found that firebug slows down execution, at least in my cases, run it without firebug and in Chrome and see if performance is still poor

Comment: yea, its perfect in chrome, so i guess its firebug.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing brackets and you must use colon between them not commas:

```
$("td input").focus( function(){
    $(this).parent().next().next().css({'visibility':'visible'});            
});
$("td input").blur( function(){
    $(this).parent().next().next().css({'visibility':'hidden'});
    if($(this).val()==""){
        $(this).parent().next().css({'visibility':'visible'});
    }
    else $(this).parent().next().css({'visibility':'hidden'});
});
```